Issues with Switching Between Multiple RDP Remote Apps in Apache Guacamole
I’ve successfully deployed Apache Guacamole on Linux (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS) and configured access to a Windows Terminal Server (WinSrv 2008/2012) via RDP. The goal is to provide access to specific applications through the browser. I must say the setup was surprisingly straightforward, especially with two-factor authentication and Active Directory integration—everything worked smoothly.
Now, here’s my issue: when I launch remote applications, they all open within a single window. I’m aware of the RDP limitations, specifically that only two concurrent connections are allowed for administrative purposes, but my question is: Has anyone worked on or come across a simple and convenient way to switch between running applications in one session for a single user?
From what I’ve found so far, intercepting the Alt + Tab keyboard input hasn’t been successfully implemented. The closest workaround I found is to use Ctrl + Alt + Shift to select the input mode, which then displays 4 buttons (Ctrl, Alt, Esc, Tab) in the bottom-right corner of the screen. Using these, I can simulate Alt + Tab, but it’s not the most efficient solution.
If anyone has a solution or can point me in the right direction, I’d greatly appreciate it!
Thanks in advance!
